# If Else in linq with anonymous object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, if-statement, casting

How to do an If Else conditional in a LINQ query?

cashierdata.useDenominations  is boolean type, i'm doing the casting to the same object .
Something like

```
IQueryable<CashierBalance> icashierBalance = _cashierDataManagement.GetIQueryableCashierBalance();
        var currencies = icashierBalance.Select(a => new
        {
            Id = a.Currency.Id,
            Name = a.Currency.Name,
            Simbol = a.Currency.Symbol,
            ShorName = a.Currency.ShortName,
            RoundingUp = a.Currency.RoundingUp,
            RoundingDown = a.Currency.RoundingDown,
            DenominationMin = a.Currency.DenominationMin,
            Denominations = cashierdata.useDenominations ? (Denomination) a.Currency.Denominations.Select(q => q )

             : (Denomination) null


        });
```

The response from the api

Unable to cast the type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Tellers.Denomination, DynamicFieldsDiagramLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' to type 'Tellers.Denomination'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Without casting

```
IQueryable<CashierBalance> icashierBalance = _cashierDataManagement.GetIQueryableCashierBalance();
        var currencies = icashierBalance.Select(a => new
        {
            Id = a.Currency.Id,
            Name = a.Currency.Name,
            Simbol = a.Currency.Symbol,
            ShorName = a.Currency.ShortName,
            RoundingUp = a.Currency.RoundingUp,
            RoundingDown = a.Currency.RoundingDown,
            DenominationMin = a.Currency.DenominationMin,
            Denominations = cashierdata.useDenominations ?  a.Currency.Denominations.Select(q => q )

             :  null


        });
```

the exception

The nested query is not supported. Operation1='Case' Operation2='Collect'

Comment: `(Denomination) a.Currency.Denominations.Select(q => q )` seems to be the case. The select might return a collection while you're casting it to `Denomination` and not `IEnumerable<Denomination>`.

Comment: What are you doing `.Select(q => q)`?

Comment: The select for `Denominations` is redundant.

Comment: Side note: You do not have to specify the property names of an anonymous object explicitly. If you do not specify the property name, the property name of the selected property is used. You can for example change `Id = a.Currency.Id,` to just `a.Currency.Id`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `IQueryable` is attempting to parse your expression and convert it into an SQL expression. This is beyond the capabilities of Entity Framework (specifically, it is unable to assign an enumerable of objects to `Denominations`).

In this case, you just want to fetch the data from the database, then perform your conversion in the .NET client.

To achieve this, convert your `IQueryable` to `LINQ2Objects` by invoking `AsEnumerable`.

```
IQueryable<CashierBalance> icashierBalance = _cashierDataManagement.GetIQueryableCashierBalance();
        var currencies = icashierBalance
                         .AsEnumerable()
                         .Select(a => new
        {
            Id = a.Currency.Id,
            Name = a.Currency.Name,
            Simbol = a.Currency.Symbol,
            ShorName = a.Currency.ShortName,
            RoundingUp = a.Currency.RoundingUp,
            RoundingDown = a.Currency.RoundingDown,
            DenominationMin = a.Currency.DenominationMin,
            Denominations = cashierdata.useDenominations ? a.Currency.Denominations.Select(q => q ) : null
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IQueryable<CashierBalance> icashierBalance = _cashierDataManagement.GetIQueryableCashierBalance();
var currencies = icashierBalance.Select(a => new
{
    Id = a.Currency.Id,
    Name = a.Currency.Name,
    Simbol = a.Currency.Symbol,
    ShorName = a.Currency.ShortName,
    RoundingUp = a.Currency.RoundingUp,
    RoundingDown = a.Currency.RoundingDown,
    DenominationMin = a.Currency.DenominationMin,
    Denominations = cashierdata.useDenominations ? a.Currency.Denominations : null
});
```